# Scrollbar on Login Page where no scrolling is needed - how to disable?

Tags: angular, ionic2

MY Ionic 2 app has a login page like this:

[image]

When I click in the email or password field the app adds a vertical scroll bar and moves the entire content a little to the top:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <p text-center padding>
    Acesse com seu E-mail<br>e senha enviada por E-mail.
  </p>


  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>E-mail</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Senha</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button full large (click)="login()">ENTRAR</button>

</ion-content>
```

How can I avoid this ugly scrolling?

I tried already:

- `<ion-content padding no-bounce>`
- `overflow: hidden;`
- `app._setDisableScroll;`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your `app.module` to the `imports` array of your `NgModule`:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  scrollPadding: false,
  scrollAssist: true,
  autoFocusAssist: false
})
```

On iOS you can additionally try to disable the scrolling with the [`Keyboard`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/) plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

Add it as a provider in your `app.module`. Then import and inject it:

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) {}
```

And then call the `disableScroll` method:

```
this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting `<content scroll="false">`? That will disable scrolling. Take a look at the examples/starters/map for a full screen map example.